# Adding image to another

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

Here is an explanation of what I need to do. It should load a photo from the gallery and display it on the screen. Then the user is able to drag a small picture of the company's mascot into the loaded photo, and finally save it.

The idea is that if you search the photo from the gallery app, you can find the original photo and also the modified photo where the mascot looks like it is in it.

The issue is that I am not really sure what classes to use in order to accomplish this. I am actually loading the photo bitmap into an `ImageView` but then I don't know how to add the mascot into the bitmap, should I use a `Canvas`? or what is the procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a canvas from original Bitmap (refers to your gallery image) as base, and draw your mascot on it, and save the thumbnail as another file in storage.

You have to calculate the position of drawing tough.

```
Bitmap base; // Get it with your own approach, this refers to gallery image
Bitmap mascot; // Get it with your own approach, this refers to mascot image

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(base);
//0f and 0f refers to coordinates of drawing, you may want to do some calculation here.
canvas.drawBitmap(mascot, 0f, 0f, null); 

// At this point base will have the mascot drawn, you may want to display it or save it somewhere else.
```

Comment: I'm currently displayin the 'base' Bitmap on an ImageView. After I draw the 'mascot' using the canvas as stated, I need to display it, can it be done by ImageView or do I have to create a custom View?

Comment: You may just do a ImageView.setImageBitmap(base) after you performed all the codes above, then you will have the new image updated. Also save it as another file in external storage so that you cna retrieve it later. EDIT: sorry did not read your question properly, you can have two imageview in your screen which the first will set with the original image, and after you finish drawing you can set the base to second image view, of course doing a setImageBitmap again with base on first ImageView will also do the effect.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do image first mutable and then add other image on it and gain make it immutable-

```
bitmap3=mutableimage3.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,true);// mutable image.


 bitmap3=mutableimage3.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,false);//immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an app called mustache madness...its an open source..and it provides exactly what you need...  https://github.com/baugarten/Android-Image-Edit  ..check its source.